# how to implement lazy load on a collection view in ios

Tags: objective-c, uikit

I need to implement lazy loading of images on a collection view after hitting webservice that is in another class. (flow is following)

1. select a category.
2. click on filter option.
3. check desired item from different categories like brands, style, price and color.
4. finally click on done. A web service should then be called for the filtered item list, which will return 20 items each time and control goes to category screen with 20 items (page #1). if more than 20 items should be shown it will load and return more items.

How can I implement this?

Answer (score 0):

Use this for Lazy Loading

https://github.com/SVProgressHUD/SVProgressHUD

You have to start like this [SVProgressHUD Show]

Stop [SVProgressHUD Dismiss]

Answer (score 0):

Basic steps

1. You should have some data-structure that represents the items in your collectionview.  For simplicity, I am going to assume that's an array.
2. Implement the UICollectionViewDataSource methods to show that array in the datasource.
3. When your webservice returns, (a) update the array (b) call `reloadData` on the collection view

Other things to know:

1. You must call reloadData on the main thread -- if you webservice code is in a background thread, use:

   ```
   dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
       // call reload here
   });
   ```
2. If you want to do minimal updates, you need to know what exactly changed. For example, if you know you just added a single item to the end of the array, you can call `insertItemsAtIndexPaths:` to express the collection view that it only needs to ask for that one new item